# android - EditText width inside TableRow

Tags: android

I've been trying to find an aswer for this but i couldn't.

I've got a TableLayout with two `TableRow`s. 
In the first one there is a `TextView` that is about `150dp` of width. In the second one there is an `EditText` which width should be about `40dp`, but the problem is that the width of the `EditText` is forced to match the width of the `TextView` that is above.

My question is, is there a way to avoid this? I mean, to make the width of the `EditText` `40dp`, no matter what the width of the `TextView` is, without creating another tablelayout?

Thanks in advance. Sorry for my limited english.

In Case someone have this problem, i solved it using the next:

Supposing that you have a table row with two or more elements, put layout_width to match_parent, then the first element layout_weight to 1 and the second element to 2. This will fill the entire row with the two elements but the second one will be double size of the first one. If you have more than two elements and one should be bigger than the others, use weight 2 on that element and weight 1 on the others.

Hope to help someone.

Comment: i would suggest something with weights like @The Dark Knight has below.

Comment: Is the layout created dinamically or from XML? In XML you can use android:layout_width="40dp" on the EditText. If you add the EditText from code, you should use a LayoutParams object and use the addView(View,LayoutParams) method of ViewGroup class. With the LayoutParams object, you can specify the size of the view in the layout.

Comment: That's the problem, setting a specify width doesn't work for me. It still changing the width to fit the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

You can make another parent for your EditText, like a LinearLayout,

So you will get:
TableLayout->TableRow->LinearLayout->EditText

Comment: I would like to avoid the use of more layouts. I Should specify in my question that i had to add rows dinmically.